# ClassNotFoundException is thrown when running ExportSnapshot

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

I'm getting a confusing ClassNotFoundException when I try to run ExportSnapshot from my HBase master node. `hbase shell` and other commands work just fine, and my cluster is fully operational.

This feels like a Classpath issue, but I don't know what I'm missing.

```
$ /usr/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot ambarismoketest-snapshot -copy-to hdfs://10.0.1.90/apps/hbase/data -mappers 16
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2015-10-13 20:05:02,339 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2015-10-13 20:05:04,351 INFO  [main] util.FSVisitor: No logs under directory:hdfs://cinco-de-nameservice/apps/hbase/data/.hbase-snapshot/impression_event_production_hbase-transfer-to-staging-20151013/WALs
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.runCopyJob(ExportSnapshot.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.run(ExportSnapshot.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.innerMain(ExportSnapshot.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.main(ExportSnapshot.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

It turns out this is because the mapreduce2 JARs are not available in the classpath. The classpath was properly set up, but I did not have the mapreduce2 client installed on that node. HBase's ExportSnapshot apparently depends on those client JARs when exporting snapshots to another cluster because it writes to HDFS.

**Fix**

If you use Ambari:

1. Load Ambari UI
2. Pull up node where you were running the ExportSnapshot from and getting the above error
3. Under "components", click "Add"
4. Click "Mapreduce 2 client"

**Background**

There's a ticket here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-9687 where the title is `ClassNotFoundException is thrown when ExportSnapshot runs against hadoop cluster where HBase is not installed on the same node as resourcemanager`. The title implies that installing resource manager is the fix and this may work; however, the crux is you need the hadoop mapreduce2 jars in the classpath and you can do that by simply installing the mapreduce2 client.

For us, specifically, the reason our snapshot exports were working one day and broken the next is that our HBase master switched on us b/c of another issue we had. Our backup HBase master did not have the mapreduce2 client JARs, but the original primary master did.